# combine two dictionary by the key which is a tuple and add new information to the tuple

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries.

The first one is

```py
target1 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda:[]))
target1[price][producer].append({  
"head": consumer_name, "tail": factory_name,
"production_id": production_id})
```

Note: The key "price" is a tuple (money,curreny_type)

The second dictionary is

```py
target2 = defaultdict(lambda: set())
target2[price].add(production_id)
```

For the target2 dictionary, the production_id and the price key (which is a tuple) are the same as the those in target1 dictionary. I want to get the length of the production_id set for each key (price) for target2. And after attaining this information I want the target1 dictionary to contain not only the (money,curreny_type) for the price key but also the length in the tuple. In this case, I want to join target2 information to target1. The output would be:

```py
target1[(money,curreny_type,length of the production_id set)][producer].append({  
"head": consumer_name, "tail": factory_name,
"production_id": production_id})
```

Comment: Can you provide an explicit example of input/output?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. thanks

Comment: Ideally, this could be one script that takes about as much code as you've shown, maybe a few imports, and hardcode the initial data. Then we can compare the actual output to the expected output.